# What happens to NORX if the same (key, nonce, header data) triple is reused

Tags: authenticated-encryption, norx

As I understand it, reusing a (key, nonce, header data) triple in NORX leaks

- the XOR of the initial common prefix (but this is zero, so only its length is leaked)
- the XOR of the first distinct blocks (which is usable by an attacker)

Is this all NORX leaks if misused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the attack model. In certain (realistic!) attack models, such as the one used for the BEAST and related attacks on TLS, security breaks down further—it [becomes](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/beer.pdf) [possible](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDUxNzM1NjMxMTk5NTczMDYwNTQBMDY3MzU5NzE4Mjg1ODQwNDU5NzUBckZGVklLdDBaQklKATAuMQEBdjI) [to decrypt](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/189) messages in a byte-by-byte fashion!

This is not specific to NORX; *any* online authenticated encryption scheme will be vulnerable to the CPSS attack if misused repeatedly, though supposedly "misuse-resistant" modes do not lose security instantly (unlike e.g. AES-GCM). Modes that resist this kind of misuse necessarily need to perform two passes over the message, rendering them offline (i.e., the entire message must be accessible during encryption).

Comment: Note that NORX allows for a header to be part of the AD and guarantees full security if that is unique (as will always be the case in TLS).  Also, one must reuse a nonce many times for this attack to work.

Comment: What is the "CPSS attack"?

Comment: Follow the link I posted in the response, Section 3.